# Probability distribution of naieve bayes in weka

Tags: java, weka

I want to run the naieve bayes classifier. I have trained this model in weka. Now for each testing instances I want to find the predicted class and the probability distribution so that with this value I can rank the instances as well.
I am running the weka from java. How can i get the probability distribution in weka java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] predictionDistribution = null;
    try {
        double clsLabel = classifier.classifyInstance(Test Instance Here);
        predictionDistribution = classifier.distributionForInstance(Test Instance Here);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to classify item\n");
    }
```

Use a `double[]` array and then use your classifier's `distributionForInstance()` method.